# MFC MDI - "Encountered an improper argument"

Tags: mfc, mdi

I have embedded VLC player into an MFC MDI application. Whenever I close the child frame which contains the embedded VLC platyer, a messagebox with the following message pops up "Encountered an improper argument". If I close the application after this messagebox pops up. It doesn't close. The application goes to background and then I have to go to Task Manager and kill the application.
This happens only in the Release build. I never encountered this error in the Debug build.
Please let me know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I solved this problem. I had written wrapper class around the libmysql in my application. The problem was due to some memory leak happening in my wrapper class.

Answer (score 1):

**"Encountered an improper argument”** will pop up when you try to access a control which is defined but is not part of the current scope. For example if you have several forms / views and you try to access a control from another form / view.

I would look at:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
```

,

```
DoDataExchange
```

and so on, and check that each ID is within the scope of the current page / view / form / dialog.

Comment: I was missing a call to DDX_Control() in DoDataExchange for the control. That produced the message "Encountered an improper argument” when I called SetWindowTextA (SetWindowText) on the control..

Answer (score 1):

Because this is the highest ranking result for any search on "encountered an improper argument" that comes from stackoverflow, let me make a note here to help others track down the source of such errors.

The popup message seems to be the default exception handler for (at least) one kind of invalid argument exception. All attempts to break into the debugger, and inspect all associated threads with the message box still on screen (and so hopefully obvious at the top of some thread's call stack) came to nothing.

Instead, I took educated guesses at where the issue might arise, and wrapped them all in high-level `try ... catch(...)` blocks. I then put a breakpoint in each of the catch clauses -- `catch (...) { // break here }`. Eventually, this approach pinpointed the error, which for me ultimately stemmed from:

```
SomeObject * pObject = nullptr;    // accidentally null
...
CString message;
message.Format( "Some value: %d", pObject->GetSomeValue() );
```

That is: instead of some exception appropriate to the null dereference, this threw the invalid argument exception. It was obvious to me that the object was invalid, and so I did not bother to pursue what kind of exception was being thrown.